# Причастный оборот. Нормы

Tags: синтаксис, причастный-оборот

Будет ли являться ошибкой, если в причастном обороте одно причастие будет страдательным, а другое — действительным, или одно будет в форме прошедшего времени, а другое — в форме настоящего?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Таких формальных ограничений нет.

> Петров, вчера скандаливший в самолёте и теперь подозреваемый в
>   убийстве, сегодня задержан.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

Приведём пример:

Только во дворе сохранился снег, ***(1) разбросанный* вдоль дороги, но (2) еще *не растаявший*.**

В этом примере два причастных оборота. Причастный оборот ― это  причастие с зависимыми словами, то есть **в одном обороте не может быть два причастия.**

Но в одном предложении  причастия могут быть разными.

Comment: Званый обед, сервированный роскошно и изобилующий редкой пищей. То, что здесь причастия, относящиеся к одному и тому же слову, стоят в разной форме, не считается ошибкой?

Comment: Существительное может иметь несколько грамматически разных определений,  при этом они  могут выражаться прилагательными,  причастиями, а также оборотами на основе прилагательных и причастий.  Связь между ними может быть союзная и бессоюзная. Таково грамматическое устройство языка, всё это разрешается.